# Can I add a custom key field to a base Acumatica table?

Tags: acumatica

Am I able to add a new, custom field to a base table that is also a key field? The specific example I have is that I want to add a UsrStepNbr field to the PMTask table which will be a key field.

Comment: It's better to do a new table and have the key fields declared as PXParent pointing to the base table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - No

Long answer - I attempted this a few years back with a customization project and when it did not work I was informed by Acumatica engineering it was not a use case that had been internally defined nor would it be supported in the future.

Comment: Excellent answer, technically there could be a way but in practice it is a very bad idea.